# How do I stop a button from executing a bound command in Xamarin.Forms using C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, data-binding

I have created a button that toggles between "Edit" and "Save".  This button has a databinding to a "Save command" in my ViewModel.

I want to stop the "Save Command" from executing until the button text is equal to "Save".

I have tried toggling `Command.CanExceute(false)` but this does not seem to work and the "Save Command" always executes regardless! Example code is posted below and is also available in my [GitHub Repositry](https://github.com/minlopalis/StackOverflowCommandExecute.git)

**MainPage.xaml**

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <App:ClientViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <StackLayout>
        <Button x:Name="EditSaveButton"
                Text="Edit"
                Command="{Binding SaveClient}"
                Clicked="EditSaveButton_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            EditSaveButton.Command.CanExecute(false);
        }

        private void EditSaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (EditSaveButton.Text == "Edit")
            {
                EditSaveButton.Text = "Save";
                EditSaveButton.Command.CanExecute(true);
            }
            else 
            {
                EditSaveButton.Text = "Edit";
                EditSaveButton.Command.CanExecute(false);
            }
        }
```

**ClientViewModel.cs**

```
    public class ClientViewModel
    {
        public Command SaveClient { get; set; }

        public ClientViewModel()
        {
            SaveClient = new Command( async () => {

                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Saved", "Client Saved", "OK");
            });
        }
    }
```

**###### UPDATE ######**

Thanks to Jason and Robert Harvey for their guidance on this.
I have changed my code to use only `Command` instead of `Clicked` and bind the text property of the button to a property in my ViewModel.  However when I execute the code the Button Text is not updating?  Any ideas why?

Main.xaml

```
    <StackLayout>
        <Button x:Name="EditSaveButton"
                Text="{Binding EditSaveButtonText}"
                Command="{Binding SaveClient}"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

ClientViewModel.cs

```
 public class ClientViewModel
    {
        public Command SaveClient { get; set; }

        public string EditSaveButtonText { get; set; }

        public ClientViewModel()
        {

            SaveClient = new Command( () => {

                if (EditSaveButtonText == "Edit")
                {
                    EditSaveButtonText = "Save";
                }
                else
                {
                    EditSaveButtonText = "Edit";
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: don't use Command and Clicked, pick one approach.  If you bind the button Text to a VM property, then your VM can determine which state it is in and act appropriately

Comment: Thanks Jason, because my code needs to perform some logic available in the ViewModel (Saving a record to a Database) I will opt for the Command option.  However my provided code isn't complete, I also need to perform some logic in the view, e.g. update the button colour etc..

Comment: You can bind the color to a VM property and use a ValueConverter

Comment: Thanks Jason, I have updated my question to include your changes but the button Text is not updating?? Any ideas why?

Comment: Your VM needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands in Xamarin implement the `ICommand` interface.

```
public interface ICommand
{
    public void Execute (Object parameter);

    public bool CanExecute (Object parameter);

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

If you're binding a Command in the button to a View Model  that implements `ICommand`, just set `CanExecute` to `false`.  *You should do this in the View Model, not the View.*

Either bind an event to the button or use a `Command`.  *Don't do both.*  If you need to change the button color, set up a binding for the button color to a property of the View Model so that you can change it there.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I have updated my question to include your changes but the button Text is not updating?? Any ideas why?

Comment: I wouldn't base it on the button's text.  Put a flag in your ViewModel to track it; something like `bool _isSaved`.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that's a really good suggestion. :)  I will do that.  As you are most likely aware and indicated by Jason above I didn't implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.